# VBA: Selecting Multiple values from one sheet based on input of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in one scenario, where using VBA I am trying to find out whether data present in Sheet2 is having any entry in sheet1. If that is having one entry then I am fetching the details of that entry from sheet1.

here is the snap of my sheet1

[image]

Here is the snap of my sheet 2

[image]

I have checked through some code and came up as below but it would be really helpful if I can get some guidance here.

Below is my code snippet

```
Sub matchOutput()
    Dim Sh1 As Range, Sh2 As Range, id As Range
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
    Dim matchIndex As Long, cnt As Long
    Set Sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A100") 'Data column in Sheet1
    Set Sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A100") 'Data column in Sheet3
    cnt = 1

    For Each id In Sh1
        Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & id.Row, ":E" & id.Row) 'Get all data in row from Sheet1
        matchIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(id, Sh2, 0) 'match Data in sheet2 to data in Sheet1
        Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & matchIndex) 'Get all data in Sheet2 based on rowindex given by match above
        rng1.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & cnt)
        cnt = cnt + 1
    Next id
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what sheet 3 is supposed to look like when the operation is complete?

Comment: I was thinking to have that in sheet 3 but ideally I want that to be in sheet 2 only. As shown in Snapshot of sheet2

Comment: So you only need the data from column `C4`? Or do you need all of it, but you get rid of the duplicate stuff from `C1`?

Comment: I'm just trying to see the before/after.

Comment: Yes, suppose I have sheet2 with C1 column where I will provide the data. That data to be matched with Sheet1 C1 and if matched then Sheet 2 will have something as shown in Snapshot of sheet2.
Yes, I need the data from C4 to C7 and need to remove duplicates from C1 from sheet 1

Comment: Please let me know if you need any more details. Looking forward for your response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222608/discussion-between-2437850-and-user1274820).